# ag-grid 3.3.3: "onModelUpdated" event is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid 3.3.3 with angular.

The following works fine:

```
$scope.myGrid = {
    rowData: $scope.data,
    columnDefs: [...],
    onModelUpdated: function(event) {
         this.api.setFloatingBottomRowData([boxes: 0, weight: 0]);
    }
};
```

But I want to reuse the code inside `onModelUpdated` on other grids...

So I've created an angular factory like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyFactory', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
        onModelUpdated: function(event) {
            //console.log(event.api);
            event.api.setFloatingBottomRowData([boxes: 0, weight: 0]);
        }
    }
}]);
```

And I'm trying to use it like this:

```
$scope.myGrid = {
    rowData: $scope.data,
    columnDefs: [...],
    onModelUpdated: MyFactory.onModelUpdated
};
```

But I'm getting an `undefined` event!

What is the event content?

When I do this: `console.log(event)` I get a pure js object...

How can I reuse my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh, sometimes I need to ask in StackOverflow just to illuminate myself.

I ended up doing this:

Factory:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyFactory', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
        onModelUpdated: function(grid) {
            grid.api.setFloatingBottomRowData([boxes: 0, weight: 0]);
        }
    }
}]);
```

grid:

```
$scope.myGrid = {
    rowData: $scope.data,
    columnDefs: [...],
    onModelUpdated: function(event) {
        MyFactory.onModelUpdated(this);
    }
};
```